# ToggleSwitch does not adhere to the Can convention

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 application (WinRT/Windows Store, no Silverlight) and I use Caliburn Micro Version 2.0.1.

According to my observations it seems to me that there is no Can convention for the
ToggleSwitch control. In a View I have a ToggleSwitch with the name "Switch". 
In the ViewModel I have two properties: "Switch" and "CanSwitch", both of type bool.

In View:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="Switch" />
```

In ViewModel:

```
public bool CanSwitch
{
    get
    {
        return ...;
    }
}

public bool Switch { get; set; }
```

I would expect that the ToggleSwitch is enabled or disabled according to the property
"CanSwitch". But this does not work. Only after established a explicit binding I get
the desiered behaviour.

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="Switch"
              IsEnabled="{Binding CanSwitch}" />
```

Is this a bug or missing feature in Caliburn Micro or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

I have modified the ViewModel that way that CanSwitch always returns false. This had no effect on the View. The ToggleSwitch is still enabled.

```
public bool Switch { get; set; }

public bool CanSwitch
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

I also set a breakpoint in the getter of CanSwitch. This breakpoint was never hit. It looks like that CanSwitch is ignored by Caliburn Micro.

Comment: Silverlight or Universal APp?

Comment: WinRT/Win Store (no Silverlight)

Comment: when you make a change to the underlying Property backer did you call make a NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>CanSwitch), where the change is made?

Comment: I checked this but without success. It seems that Caliburn Micro ignores the CanSwitch flag altogether. See update in post.

Comment: wired up an example and I think you are absolutely correct, going to put a bug in on this...

Comment: So, I tried this. The binding works when I place the `ToggleButton` in a `Grid`; but it doesn't bind when I place it inside a `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool switch;

public bool CanSwitch
{
    get { return switch; }
    set 
    {
        switch= value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => switch);
    }
}
```